# Better way to rewrite windowing function

Tags: sql, postgresql, windowing

Production table have more than 32 M records, for testing purpose created synthetic tab which have 6M records. The below query is taking more than 10 min and killed the process in middle.
Any suggestion, how can we optimize below query.

```
select 
    name
    ,sales
    ,sum(sales) over(partition by name order by sales_dated_on rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as running_total
    ,first_value(sales) over(partition by name order by sales_dated_on ) as first_sales
    ,last_value(sales) over(partition by name order by sales_dated_on desc ) as first_sales
    ,sum(sales) over() as total_sales
    ,sum(sales) over(partition by name ) as total_sales_by_name
from demo.window_test wt ;
```

### Explain Plan:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
WindowAgg  (cost=1153310.26..2678815.36 rows=5999981 width=51) (actual time=99673.366..101631.354 rows=6000000 loops=1)                                                       |
  Output: name, sales, (sum(sales) OVER (?)), (first_value(sales) OVER (?)), (last_value(sales) OVER (?)), sum(sales) OVER (?), (sum(sales) OVER (?)), sales_dated_on         |
  Buffers: shared hit=15762 read=22455, temp read=22522984 written=199339                                                                                                     |
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1153310.26..2603815.59 rows=5999981 width=43) (actual time=30058.611..96819.860 rows=6000000 loops=1)                                                  |
        Output: name, sales_dated_on, sales, (last_value(sales) OVER (?)), (sum(sales) OVER (?)), (first_value(sales) OVER (?)), sum(sales) OVER (?)                          |
        Buffers: shared hit=15762 read=22455, temp read=22438358 written=156857                                                                                               |
        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1153310.26..2513815.88 rows=5999981 width=35) (actual time=21230.484..91691.264 rows=6000000 loops=1)                                            |
              Output: name, sales_dated_on, sales, (last_value(sales) OVER (?)), (sum(sales) OVER (?)), first_value(sales) OVER (?)                                           |
              Buffers: shared hit=15762 read=22455, temp read=22373366 written=123159                                                                                         |
              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1153310.26..2408816.21 rows=5999981 width=31) (actual time=21230.475..32732.391 rows=6000000 loops=1)                                      |
                    Output: name, sales_dated_on, sales, (last_value(sales) OVER (?)), sum(sales) OVER (?)                                                                    |
                    Buffers: shared hit=15762 read=22455, temp read=89153 written=89461                                                                                       |
                    ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=1153310.26..2303816.54 rows=5999981 width=23) (actual time=21230.460..29881.325 rows=6000000 loops=1)                         |
                          Output: name, sales_dated_on, sales, (last_value(sales) OVER (?))                                                                                   |
                          Sort Key: wt.name, wt.sales_dated_on                                                                                                                |
                          Presorted Key: wt.name                                                                                                                              |
                          Full-sort Groups: 9  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 30kB  Peak Memory: 30kB                                                                |
                          Pre-sorted Groups: 9  Sort Method: external merge  Average Disk: 22207kB  Peak Disk: 22208kB                                                        |
                          Buffers: shared hit=15762 read=22455, temp read=89153 written=89461                                                                                 |
                          ->  WindowAgg  (cost=1019809.47..1139809.09 rows=5999981 width=23) (actual time=20317.487..26224.097 rows=6000000 loops=1)                          |
                                Output: name, sales_dated_on, sales, last_value(sales) OVER (?)                                                                               |
                                Buffers: shared hit=15762 read=22455, temp read=58332 written=58487                                                                           |
                                ->  Sort  (cost=1019809.47..1034809.42 rows=5999981 width=19) (actual time=20317.469..22908.680 rows=6000000 loops=1)                         |
                                      Output: name, sales_dated_on, sales                                                                                                     |
                                      Sort Key: wt.name, wt.sales_dated_on DESC                                                                                               |
                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 176024kB                                                                                             |
                                      Buffers: shared hit=15762 read=22455, temp read=58332 written=58487                                                                     |
                                      ->  Seq Scan on demo.window_test wt  (cost=0.00..98216.81 rows=5999981 width=19) (actual time=0.015..890.826 rows=6000000 loops=1)|
                                            Output: name, sales_dated_on, sales                                                                                               |
                                            Buffers: shared hit=15762 read=22455
```

SQL script:

```
create table demo.window_test(name varchar(20),sales int,sales_dated_on timestamp);

insert into demo.window_test
select 
    --concat('Group' ,id::text),
    concat('Group',floor(random()*(10-1)+1)::INT) as name
    ,floor(random()*(500-1)+1)::INT as sales_amount
    ,now() -'1 days'::interval * random() * ((10000+1)-1)
from 
    generate_series(1,10) as id
    ,generate_series(1,600000) ;
```

Comment: 1. explain plan  2. explain plan and 3. explain plan.   An explain plan is the goto tool for any performance tuning, you should provide it in the question (NOT as an image please). Once we see what that explain plan says we might be able to help. Additionally the full DDL of that table would also help. NOte as there is only 1 table involved probably the only thing available for tuning is indexing

Comment: is "name" the only thing you can partition by to get the desired results?  How many chars  are allowed in name? are there any indexes on name?

Comment: This SQL statement returns 6M rows on a 6M table, and it is not possible to return 6M in a short time.

Comment: How often do you run the query? Can you tolerate slightly stale data, i.e. is once or twice a day summation be enough? If you can then consider a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

Comment: Added explain plan

Comment: actually we are doing more windowing function for 32 M records. I couldn't remember all column operation. Most of the columns related to sum,avg, first and last operations only.

Comment: any recommendation to optimize the sql.. Please share  your thoughts

Comment: looks like it has to sort the data by wt.name, and wt.sales_date; I am not familiar with Postgresql but it could help 1. if you have an index on those, and 2 if you use CLUSTER option with that index (to keep them closer). but if you have no influence on the underlying table I doubt that you can improve this query

Comment: external merge: This indicates that the data set was too large to fit into memory  and had to be sorted using disk space. This occurs for (wt.name) &  also (wt.name, wt.sales_dated_on DESC ) . Given the production data is 5x teh size I don't see scope for a massive  tuning improvement.  The suggestion by Belayer for a materialized view seems to be good advice.

Comment: You said it took 10 minutes but your plan clearly says under 2 (101 secs).

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? As @crvv pointed out this query will return every record, so what are you going to do with a 32M row resultset in Production?

Comment: Could you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `demo.window_test` table?

Comment: The above query plan  i captured using DBeaver tool. When i ran the query it is giving only 200 record for short and if i scroll again it is taking more time to load. this process i continued for more than 10 min and it is not reached 6 M records..  @Richard Huxton

Comment: That's just DBeaver fetching 200 and then 200 more. It's DBeaver, not your server. Increase the number of records to fetch at a time in dbeaver's settings, or use its feature to execute and output the results directly into a file. For the record, it's not a feature I like. I ask it to fetch 2000, and if I should happen to scroll to the bottom, it really is upsetting when it auto-executes the query to go fetch more. Especially when the results took 20+ minutes to get. "Auto Fetch Next Segment" is the checkbox to unclick in Editors>Data Editor.

Comment: From your `CREATE TABLE` statement it seems you are not using any indexes. Given that you do `partition by name order by sales_dated_on` it might be good to have an index on `name, sales_dated_on`?

Comment: You output two columns named "first_sales", and 2nd of them looks like it is just a copy of the sales column, just computed very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your use of DBeaver is fundamentally broken.  Each time you fetch a new page, it reruns the entire query. Because of your window functions, it does not get to stop early the way some queries can when you only fetch part of the rows. You can probably configure DBeaver not to do this, or you can just use a different tool, or you can work with the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` rather than running the query raw (but in that case, you would ignoring the time it takes to send the data over the network and doing whatever the client does with the data once it is sent, but since you ask about window functions and that network/client time is independent of Window functions that is probably OK.)  Once you stop using DBeaver in this broken way, do you still have a problem or is the current performance good enough?
2. Your shown column `last_value(sales) over(partition by name order by sales_dated_on desc)` seems silly.  Using the default framing, the last row in each frame is just the same thing as the current row, barring ties in the ordering column.  So this is just an expensive way to duplicate the "sales" column.  And if there are ties, then which one of them do you want to return?  Including this calculation causes an extra sort to be done. Although this is partially saved by it being only an incremental sort not a full sort.  If you can't just get rid of this but rather have to fix the framing, then doing that will probably make it even slower yet, but you might just have to live with that.
3. first_values with default framing is not implemented very efficiently in PostgreSQL.  It does not just cache the first value for each partition and copy it out.  Instead, it keeps jumping back and forth between adding the current row to the end of the frame, then jumping to the first row of the frame to read the value.  This is particularly inefficient when the frame spills to disk.  So increase work_mem to as large as you think is safe to partially ameliorate this.
4. If you can do an index-only scan to get the data already in order, that could avoid the sort.  An index to support this on your current query might be `(name, sales_dated_on, sales)`.  But since sorting is only about 1/4 of your run time anyway, there is a limit to how much improvement this can get you.
5. Why are you doing this at all?  How many times do you really want to be fetching 32M records, and what are you going to do with them?